# Inject Entity Framework DbContext using Ninject in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I have just landed in dependency injection world.

I have the following custom DbContext-

```
public partial class SkyTrackerContext: DbContext
{
    public SkyTrackerContext(): base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new SkyTrackerDBInitializer());
    }
}
```

Would like inject SkyTrackerContext in this base controller-

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController() {}

    [Inject]
    public SkyTrackerContext MyDbContext { get; set; }
 }
```

Sample usage-

```
public class LoginController : BaseController
{            
    public ActionResult ValidateLogin(Login login) 
    {
      var query = MyDbContext.Persons.Where(.....);
    }
}
```

What should I write in NinjectWebCommon.cs to inject this context ?

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    try
    {
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
     }
     catch
     {
         kernel.Dispose();
         throw;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should avoid method injection. Instead, use constructor injection. In other words:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly DbContext context;

    public BaseController(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, as far as the Ninject config goes, it's extremely simple:

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<SkyTrackerContext>().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Because the whole point of dependency injection is that the class with the dependency shouldn't know or care how it's implemented. If your controller is going to have knowledge of `SkyTrackerContext`, then it might as well new it up itself.

Comment: Well, Thanks a lot. But then why [Inject] attribute? Sorry, I am very new in DI.

Comment: Well, like I said, you shouldn't be using that anyways. `[Inject]` is only necessary for method injection, and that's very frowned upon in general. Doing constructor injection, as I demonstrated, is the preferred method.

Comment: If I adopt your approach, I get exception- BaseController does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. Any help?

Comment: You may not have Ninject installed correctly. It's not hooking into the controller creation, so your context is not being injected. As a result, MVC tries to just new it up without any constructor params and there's no parameterless constructor to do that with.

Comment: Assuming that the `SkyTrackerContext` has a property `public DbSet<Track> Tracks { get; set; }`, how can you create a link query like `context.Tracks.Where(t=>t.Id == 1);`? I agree that the dependency shouldn't know or care how it's implemented, but it should have a useful interface to communicate with. A default DbContext does not provide any access to entities, or does it?