# ApplicationDbContext Object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm ASP.Net MVC trainee.
and I use Entity Framework.
but I'm Tense for create an instance from ApplicationDbContext in every controller class.
And I think that will make a huge size in server memory, is what's happen is that the the asp move the database to memory? or just create an object with references?.
is create a static object of ApplicationDbContext will make things better?
And what's the ideal way to work with Entity Framwork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Repository + Dependency Injection** can be a good practice.
You can use a generic repository and inject your DbContext into that for only once.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I have no idea what are you talking about.

Comment: When I work, I just use a basic asp `mvc` 5 approach, I just use `ApplicationDbContext` class with `LinQ` methods and `SaveShanges` method.

Comment: To keep it simple, you can ignore Repository and just focus on Dependency Injection pattern. Ninject is a good tool to implement that. Just search for dependency injection and you will see plenty of resources to read. If it didn't help, feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: After studying dependency injection concept, you use these two links to impliment what you need:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347607/inject-entity-framework-dbcontext-using-ninject-in-asp-net-mvc5  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172448/how-to-inject-the-entity-framework-dbcontext-into-the-configurationbasedreposito/16174311

Comment: Thank you so much. I will see and study them and back to you to complete with Repository. but I'm sorry form my urgency, I just would ask you again about how `ApplicationDbContext` object has been created and worked, if I have an 100 clients online on my website, is that means there are 100 hundred `ApplicationDbContext` objects in memory? and how I can observe the memory? and the most important question is how I can remove all objects and data that I don't need them after the view is sent to client?

Comment: Entity Framework and Garbage Collector handle the connections and disposals for you and you don't need to worry about them. Here are some other links that may answer your concerns: 

https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/ 

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359667/is-it-ok-to-create-an-entity-framework-datacontext-object-and-dispose-it-in-a-us

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666824/entity-framework-and-context-dispose